# What type of drupal module should I produce for this spec?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I'm new to drupal and need to write a module that consumes a feed from an eprints repository (the result of which is a block of JSON that I'll format -- eprints is a document repository and I'll be querying it with userids which are email addresses) and outputs the result in the main content body, but which isn't all the content on there. So the main body content of a page on which this module appears should be like so:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| User editable content                     |
+-------------------------------------------+

Title of my module

+-------------------------------------------+
| Output of my module, configured by admins |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

So I need to allow administrators to add this module to arbitrary pages and to configure it per page -- that is, when the admins add the module to a particular page they should be able to give a userid for which to query the repos for that particular page, so the content is different on each instance of the module.

Does this make sense? I'm guessing this is a node module, but I've read that node modules occupy an entire page -- it's important that I can combine the module output with some arbitrary editable content. Is this possible? If so, which type of module do I need and where can I read more about it? Either a HOWTO/tutorial or a simple example to learn from would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple "instances" of a drupal module.

I wasn't really able to figure out what part of this was related to eprints but everything else should be possible to do with just fields and views.

Comment: The eprints bit is some code that consumes a feed like `http://eprints.mysite/USERID` and includes the result on the page, so on I can have, e.g., pages /people/jaybee and /people/DontCare4Free and on each page we see our own feed from eprints. So I'll read about fields and views, thanks. Edit: Skimming the docs, fields are what I need. Ta.